# Gradle: Execution failed for task on Linux

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio v.2 and was going crazy since I couldn't build (with gradle) the simple template project that it creates for you. I found the solution and decided to share so that it's a smoother transition for others.

**The error message**

Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyApplication:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Running /opt/intellij/android_studio/v.2/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt failed. See output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging around I figured it out: my linux system didn't have the right **32bit** libraries installed. when I ran the following command I found which libraries were missing:

```
linux-t1h0:/opt/gradle/latest # ldd /opt/intellij/android_studio/v.2/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7760000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf773e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7739000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf771e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf7707000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf76c3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf750e000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7761000)
```

BTW, look at the log file at ~/.AndroidStudioPreview/system/log/idea.log and you'll what exactly is going on.

After installing libz.so.1, libstdc++.so.6, and libgcc_s.so.1 everything started working.

Hope this helps.

Vladimir